# AvAudioEngine tapping input node not working on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avfoundation, avaudioengine

i'm using AvAudioEngine to record audio on ios Devices.
I'm using the following code to start tapping the input node

```
self.forcedMonoAudioFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatInt16 sampleRate:44100 channels:1 interleaved:NO];  


[self.mMicrophoneNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:self.forcedMonoAudioFormat  block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when) {  

        if(isRecording) {  
               .  
               .  
               ,  
          }  

}];
```

This code works fine on all devices except on iPhone 4s.

On iPhone 4s the block is not called..

another interesting thing is that the installtap line is called twice:

1. once on the main thread
2. on a messengerQueue - at that point the MicrophoneNode is Nil

although there is only one place in the code that its beling called.

This does not happen on any other type of device.

If anyone has any insight on this behaviour I would more than appreciate it!

thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this? My AVAudioEngine can handle playing many nodes in new devices but not sound when on 4s.

Comment: I havent solved it really. but I have observed that this does not occur when headphones are plugged in. This leads me to think its something to do with the AudioSession configuration.